# How can I determine if a dynamically-created DOM element has been added to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

[**According to spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html), only the `BODY` and `FRAMESET` elements provide an "onload" event to attach to, but I would like to know when a dynamically-created DOM element has been added to the DOM in JavaScript.

The super-naive heuristics I am currently using, which work, are as follows:

- Traverse the **parentNode** property of the element back until I find the ultimate ancestor (i.e. parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.etc until parentNode is null)
- If the ultimate ancestor has a defined, non-null **body** property

  - assume the element in question is part of the dom
- else

  - repeat these steps again in 100 milliseconds

What I am after is either confirmation that what I am doing is sufficient (again, it is working in both IE7 and FF3) or a better solution that, for whatever reason, I have been completely oblivious to; perhaps other properties I should be checking, etc.

---

EDIT: I want a browser-agnostic way of doing this, I don't live in a one-browser world, unfortunately; that said, browser-specific information is appreciated, but please note which browser you know that it *does* work in. Thanks!

Comment: How can you not know when some content gets added to you document? Are you not the author of the page?

Comment: @Sergey: The more you abstract things, the more likely it becomes that the one hand doesn't know what the other's doing.

Comment: Exactly - I am building a 'widget' that will need to know, internally, when it has been added to the DOM - but since I am not necessarily the consumer, I will not know when because the client code will determine that.

Comment: IMG's onload event is not part of the W3C spec though. Besides, I want this functionality for more than images, and so it wouldn't do me a lot of good and would be a bit more brittle besides.

Comment: The browser has a method for determining if one node is inside of another: `Node.contains`. Added an answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13725984/101869

Answer (score 30, accepted):

UPDATE: For anyone interested in it, here is the implementation I finally used:

```
function isInDOMTree(node) {
   // If the farthest-back ancestor of our node has a "body"
   // property (that node would be the document itself), 
   // we assume it is in the page's DOM tree.
   return !!(findUltimateAncestor(node).body);
}
function findUltimateAncestor(node) {
   // Walk up the DOM tree until we are at the top (parentNode 
   // will return null at that point).
   // NOTE: this will return the same node that was passed in 
   // if it has no ancestors.
   var ancestor = node;
   while(ancestor.parentNode) {
      ancestor = ancestor.parentNode;
   }
   return ancestor;
}
```

The reason I wanted this is to provide a way of synthesizing the `onload` event for DOM elements. Here is that function (although I am using something slightly different because I am using it in conjunction with [**MochiKit**](http://www.mochikit.com/)):

```
function executeOnLoad(node, func) {
   // This function will check, every tenth of a second, to see if 
   // our element is a part of the DOM tree - as soon as we know 
   // that it is, we execute the provided function.
   if(isInDOMTree(node)) {
      func();
   } else {
      setTimeout(function() { executeOnLoad(node, func); }, 100);
   }
}
```

For an example, this setup could be used as follows:

```
var mySpan = document.createElement("span");
mySpan.innerHTML = "Hello world!";
executeOnLoad(mySpan, function(node) { 
   alert('Added to DOM tree. ' + node.innerHTML);
});

// now, at some point later in code, this
// node would be appended to the document
document.body.appendChild(mySpan);

// sometime after this is executed, but no more than 100 ms after,
// the anonymous function I passed to executeOnLoad() would execute
```

Hope that is useful to someone.

NOTE: the reason I ended up with this solution rather than [**Darryl's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220188/how-can-i-determine-if-a-dynamically-created-dom-element-has-been-added-to-the-do/220224#220224) was because the getElementById technique only works if you are within the same document; I have some iframes on a page and the pages communicate between each other in some complex ways - when I tried this, the problem was that it couldn't find the element because it was part of a different document than the code it was executing in.

Comment: I tried the performance and walking the dom tree is faster as long as the element is not present, http://jsperf.com/is-in-dom

Answer (score 22):

The most straightforward answer is to make use of the [`Node.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.contains) method, supported by Chrome, Firefox (Gecko), Internet Explorer, Opera, and Safari. Here is an example:

```
var el = document.createElement("div");
console.log(document.body.contains(el)); // false
document.body.appendChild(el);
console.log(document.body.contains(el)); // true
document.body.removeChild(el);
console.log(document.body.contains(el)); // false
```

Ideally, we would use `document.contains(el)`, but that doesn't work in IE, so we use `document.body.contains(el)`.

Unfortunately, you still have to poll, but checking whether an element is in the document yet is very simple:

```
setTimeout(function test() {
  if (document.body.contains(node)) {
    func();
  } else {
    setTimeout(test, 50);
  }
}, 50);
```

If you're okay with adding some CSS to your page, here's another clever technique that uses animations to detect node insertions: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/04/25/i-want-a-damnodeinserted/

Comment: `contains` is not a method of document - it's on the `body` property. So, `document.contains` will not work, you have to access it via the body like this: `document.body.contains`

Comment: @JasonBunting, both will work. `contains` is a method of all `Node` objects. Both `document` and `document.body` are `Node` objects, as are all HTML elements.

Comment: Huh, well in IE 9, document.contains == undefined, but document.body.contains != undefined. So, it doesn't necessarily seem to be the case, thus my comment. :)

Comment: the hack in the link you posted was very helpful and worked like a charm in my case

Comment: Does this check down the tree though? If you added another node as a child of the first node, then called document.body.contains(childNode) would it find the childNode which has a parent node before the document node?

Comment: @RobEvans, indeed it will.

Comment: This method fails to detect dynamically added nodes in Edge (v42+) and Firefox (v62+). Chrome (v70) works and I haven't tested Safari. I'm trying to figure out why but haven't found anything yet. Of course, in my case, I'm actually checking for `(parent) div.contains(child div)` rather than `document.contains` so not sure if that's supposed to behave differently.

Answer (score 9):

Can you no do a `document.getElementById('newElementId');` and see if that returns true. If not, like you say, wait 100ms and try again?

Comment: What if it does not have an id? Not going to work then, and this may be the case. Good answer otherwise...maybe I will see if this will work for some of my needs, and use the other method in case I don't have an id.

Comment: Why not just add an id? You can add a unique id using some kind of random string and then just look for that one. I know you don't like jQuery, but with jQuery you could easily find it based on maybe a class, parent or child.

Comment: True, this may be a good way to do it - I will have to think about it a bit though...thanks. LOL @ me not liking jQuery. I do like it, I just don't like when people think it is the answer to every JavaScript question around. :)

Comment: So, I like this and Borgar's ideas too. I could test to see if the element under question has an ID property; if so, use that with getElementById, else create a random, hopefully-unique ID and assign it; when getElementById finds it, remove the originally-non-existent ID and go forward from there.

Comment: I like this idea. It's succinct. It's practically a certainty that document.getElementById() will work, if anything does. :-)

Comment: True that - simplicity, consistency and reliability across browsers would make this the better solution; I really don't want to write browser-specific code so I will change the approved answer.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of walking the DOM tree up to the document element just use `element.ownerDocument`.
see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.ownerDocument
and do this:

```
element.ownerDocument.body.contains(element)
```

and you're good.

Answer (score 5):

**A [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is what you should use to detect when an element has been added to the DOM.** MutationObservers are now widely supported across all modern browsers (Chrome 26+, Firefox 14+, IE11, Edge, Opera 15+, etc).

Here's a simple example of how you can use a `MutationObserver` to listen for when an element is added to the DOM.

For brevity, I'm using jQuery syntax to build the node and insert it into the DOM.

```
var myElement = $("<div>hello world</div>")[0];

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
   if (document.contains(myElement)) {
        console.log("It's in the DOM!");
        observer.disconnect();
    }
});

observer.observe(document, {attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree:true});

$("body").append(myElement); // console.log: It's in the DOM!
```

The `observer` event handler will trigger whenever any node is added or removed from the `document`. Inside the handler, we then perform a `contains` check to determine if `myElement` is now in the `document`.

You don't need to iterate over each MutationRecord stored in `mutations` because you can perform the `document.contains` check directly upon `myElement`.

To improve performance, replace `document` with the specific element that will contain `myElement` in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You could query **document.getElementsByTagName("*").length** or create a custom appendChild function like the folllowing:

```
var append = function(parent, child, onAppend) {
  parent.appendChild(child);
  if (onAppend) onAppend(child);
}

//inserts a div into body and adds the class "created" upon insertion
append(document.body, document.createElement("div"), function(el) {
  el.className = "created";
});
```

**Update**

*By request, adding the information from my comments into my post*

There was a [comment by John Resig](http://ajaxian.com/archives/peppy-css3-selector-engine#comments) on the Peppy library on Ajaxian today that seemed to suggest that his Sizzle library might be able to handle DOM insertion events. I'm curious to see if there will be code to handle IE as well

Following on the idea of polling, I've read that some element properties are not available until the element has been appended to the document (for example element.scrollTop), maybe you could poll that instead of doing all the DOM traversal.

One last thing: in IE, one approach that might be worth exploring is to play with the onpropertychange event. I reckon appending it to the document is bound to trigger that event for at least one property.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments that appear directly under my question, I may not be in control of when the object is added to the DOM, otherwise I wouldn't even ask this question. But thank you for responding!

Comment: As for your first idea, that isn't as narrow a heuristic as I need - other code could add DOM elements and I would have to assume that when the length changed, it was because *my* element was being added...such an assumption is antithetical to the determinism I need.

Comment: I see. There was a comment by John Resig on the Peppy library on Ajaxian today that seemed to suggest that his Sizzle library might be able to handle DOM insertion events. I'm curious to see if there will be code to handle IE as well.

Comment: Following on the idea of polling, I've read that some element properties are not available until the element has been appended to the document (for example element.scrollTop), maybe you could poll that instead of doing all the DOM traversal.

Comment: Yeah, something like that might be nice, although I thought the Sizzle project was simply to provide for a faster selector implementation, not anything more. Either way, Resig is a pimp.

Comment: One last thing: in IE, one approach that might be worth exploring is to play with the onpropertychange event. I reckon appending it to the document is bound to trigger that event for at least one property.

Comment: Interesting idea - I might check into that too, thanks lhorie; when I get time I will research this a bit more, but for now, at least, I have sufficient; traversing and polling definitely sucks though!

Comment: lhorie, would you mind adding these ideas to your actual answer (just edit it)? I think they add value, but since they are comments (which can be deleted easily by just about anyone with the rep) they are not as potentially useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a perfect world you could hook the mutation events. I have doubts that they work reliably even on standards browsers. It sounds like you've already implemented a mutation event so you could possibly add this to use a native mutation event rather than timeout polling on browsers that support those.

I've seen DOM-change implementations that monitor changes by comparing `document.body.innerHTML` to last saved `.innerHTML`, which isn't exactly elegant (but works). Since you're ultimately going to check if a specific node has been added yet, then you're better off just checking that each interrupt.

Improvements I can think of are <del>using `.offsetParent` rather than `.parentNode` as it will likely cut a few parents out of your loop</del> (see comments). Or using `compareDocumentIndex()` on all but IE and testing `.sourceIndex` propery for IE (should be -1 if node isn't in the DOM).

This might also help: [X browser compareDocumentIndex implementaion by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/comparing-document-position/).

Comment: Turns out that offsetParent will not always work very well...it doesn't always get back to the Document itself, whereas traversing up the tree with parentNode will, if the node is part of the DOM tree; else it ultimately returns null. Not all paths up the tree with offsetParent work like this.

Comment: Also, offsetParent isn't part of the DOM spec, apparently: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.offsetParent What's more, it "returns null when the element has style.display set to 'none'" which would screw things up a bit for me.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `DOMNodeInserted` event (or `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument`).

Edit: It is entirely possible these events are not supported by IE, but I can't test that right now.

Comment: Thanks - am I right to assume that this is a Mozilla/Firefox/Gecko specific idiom?

Comment: No, you have no this right. This is DOM-Events standard idiom.

Comment: Got it. That said, I don't think IE (the red-headed step-child of browsers) supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution to the problem extracted from the jQuery code.
The following function can be used to check if a node is attached to the DOM or if it is "disconnected".

```
function isDisconnected( node ) {
    return !node || !node.parentNode || node.parentNode.nodeType === 11;
}
```

A nodeType === 11 defines a DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE, which is a node not connected to the document object.

For further information see the following article by John Resig:
http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: Doesn't work as expected I'm afraid:

var ol = document.createElement('ol');
var li = ol.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
ol.id = 'playtime';
isDisconnected(li); // returns false, I expect it to return true
document.getElementById('playtime'); // returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
var finalElement=null;
```

I am building dom objects in a loop, when the loop is on the last cycle and the `lastDomObject` is created then:

```
 finalElement=lastDomObject;
```

leave loop:

```
while (!finalElement) { } //this is the delay...
```

The next action can use any of the newly created dom objects. It worked on the first try.

Answer (score -1):

Neither of **DOMNodeInserted** or **DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument** events is supported in IE. Another missing from IE [only] feature of DOM is **compareDocumentPosition** function that is designed to do what its name suggests.

As for the suggested solution, I think there is no better one (unless you do some dirty tricks like overwriting native DOM members implementations)

Also, correcting the title of the question: dynamically created Element is part of the DOM from the moment it is created, it can be appended to a document fragment, or to another element, but it might not be appended to a document.

I also think that the problem you described is not the problem that you have, this one looks to be rather one of the potential solutions to you problem. Can you probably explain in details the use case?

Comment: Thanks for responding - the problem I described *is* the problem I am having, but thanks for trying to read my mind regardless. :) I have abstracted the details of my problem to the point that an answer to this question will be sufficient to solve my more specific problem.