# Find out if loaded image is not valid (e.g. is a 404 error page)

Tags: javascript, gwt

does someone know a way, how I could find out if a loaded image is not an image because e.g. a 404 error was returned?

In case of an error I would like to set my image URL to e.g. white image.

I can't use server-side techniques like 404-error-handling or servlets, because I want to serve my images with Amazon S3 which doesn't have error handling or redirecting to a "default file" in case the requested image was not found.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Answer (score 7):

The `Image` class has an `addErrorHandler` method. Register an error handler, which is fired in case the image was not loaded correctly. In this handler you can than set the image to a default image.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded/3016076#3016076) useful. It uses jQuery but the idea of detecting that an image was not correctly loaded in the browser is well handled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the state of error handling was when this question was asked but S3  currently has 404 error handling. I use that to generate thumbs on demand.

1. Setup the bucket for static website hosting
2. Add a redirection rule under the static website hosting section such as:

   ```
   <RoutingRules>
     <RoutingRule>
       <Condition>
         <KeyPrefixEquals/>
         <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
       </Condition>
       <Redirect>
         <HostName>yoursite.com</HostName>
         <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>image/generate/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
       </Redirect>
     </RoutingRule>
   </RoutingRules>
   ```

In the above case a missing image (i.e. cat.jpg) will cause a call to:

```
http://yoursite.com/image/generate/cat.jpg
```

In my case I use that to deliver thumbnails.

Here's a use case:

```
<img src="http://awsbucketurl.com/thumb_cat.jpg">
```

This causes a 404 triggered by S3 which then calls my site with the url. I see that it is prefixed with 'thumb_' and will then fetch cat.jpg from S3, resize, upload thumb to S3 for next time and deliver it as well to browser for this session.

One caveat: If the image is called by a caching system then it will not receive the new image after the 404 but instead store the missing image.