# how to know when the image was loaded if I change the src with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I change the **src** of an **img** tag with javascript

### is there a way to determine when the browser has fully loaded the image ?

I use this here: http://mrgsp.md:8080/prodinner/Meal

if you click on a **change picture** link, and than drag and drop an image from your desktop/other dir to the big button on that popup the src of the center image is going to be changed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser-independent way to detect when image has been loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neat site by the way that is cool.

Here is how you can do it in jquery.

[Browser-independent way to detect when image has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded)