# How to detect page load status after modification?

Tags: javascript

When user clicks on a button i load an array of images (there could be from 1 to 1000...). Is it possible somehow detect when last image is loaded?

Comment: when last image is loaded? means you asked abt TIME...?

Comment: How are you loading the array of images?

Comment: You could attach `onload`event listener to the last image.

Comment: @andyb just adding new elements to the DOM

Comment: @Pandian time, moment, end - nothing special, just need to remove loading message

Comment: Do you know how many images you're going to load before you start?

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen i could

Comment: It would help if you could add some code to the question so we can see how you are adding the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define and `onload` event for each image and in the event increment a counter until the last one is loaded, which would be the length of your array.

Comment: can you provide an example with `onload`?

Comment: The `onload` event is not supported by the W3C standard; not all browsers need to or have to support this.

Comment: good point. i was thinking you could use jQuery and the `load` handler. but that is still not perfect... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded