# I want to use an onload function on an image in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load, onload

I need to check when an image is loaded. The result has to be something like this:

```
  $('.testimage').onload(function() {
  // do stuff
  });
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser-independent way to detect when image has been loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `onload` method in jQuery (although there is an underlying `onload` property on the raw DOM). There is a `load` method but it (confusingly) has different meanings (See http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ and http://api.jquery.com/load/ ) depending on the context you use it in, and the version that attaches a load event handler has been deprecated.

The standard jQuery way to attach event handlers is via the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
  $('.testimage').on('load', function() {
      // do stuff
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 $('.testimage').load(function() {
  // do stuff
 });
```

if you are using jquery version 1.7+

```
 $('.testimage').on('load', function() {
  // do stuff
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/itdiver/TDu3s/)

```
<img src="http://***.**/***/***/book.gif" alt="Book" id="book" width="200">

$('#book').load(function () {
    alert('loaded');
});
```

Comment: Two people have already given (more or less) identical answers. One of them over 10 minutes before you gave this answer. If you're going to answer a question that has already been answered, make it a better answer.

Comment: @Quentin my answer is better, because i add fiddle and you can see it workelly

Comment: Copying the code into a fiddle is worthy of a comment, not a new answer.