# The moment an image has finished loading

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing

This maybe a real stupid question so I apologise and i stand ready to delete my own question.

I have an image element in my HTML5 app to which i give an id of 'img1' like so:

```
<img id="img1" src="" /`>
```

I assign a module variable to this element like so:

```
var staticImgArray = document.getElementById('img1');
```

I set the image src by binding it to a Generic handler (I am using  ASP.NET)

```
staticImgArray .src = 'get image from this link';
```

Now I need to know at what point has the image finished loading. At the moment I use this code to determine that:

```
staticImgArray.onload = function () {
   //image has loaded
};
staticImgArray.onerror = function () {
   //image has not loaded properly but has finished trying?
};
```

But...

```
staticImgArray.src = 'get image from this link';
**//image has finished loading here..??**

//other code runs here afterwards
```

...if the above statement is not true then does that not imply the loading of the image is done asynchronously?

Thanks

Comment: Try looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded

Comment: Thanks, I need to read this and take it all in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading is async. Here is a working example that shows the `onload` callback firing after image loaded but js execution will not be stopped

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4to3Lazd/)

---

```
var staticImgArray = document.getElementById('img1');

staticImgArray.onload = function () {
   //other code after image loads runs here

    console.log('loaded');
};

staticImgArray.src = 'http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/c050fce5e0094decb57fdb53f4ca4254.jpg'

console.log('I fire first though');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I looked at the links sent by the other poster and it implies that you cannot always rely on th 'onload' event to work?

Comment: Quick test in Chrome, FF, IE9+ shows it's working. See what works for you though. Reading through that SO post, this still seems like a reasonable way to go about this