# Detect whether an image failed to load

Tags: javascript

Edit: bolded the reason this isn't a duplicate. It was already three words from the start, it was already repeated for emphasis.

Given an HTMLImageElement **that's already loaded (load or error event already fired)**, does anybody know of a good way to tell if the load failed?

Strategies I've come up with:

- `img.src = img.src` then catch the load or error event. Browsers seem to optimize this away and not actually make a network request, but I'd be much more comfortable with a solution that doesn't assume optimizations.
- Change the alt text then see if the size changed. Very tough to make this robustly interoperate with the page's CSS and external event listeners on the image.

Edit: bolded the reason this isn't a duplicate, because apparently putting it in the first sentence and wording it two different ways still didn't get anybody to pay attention.

Comment: How about just `img.src = img.src + '?tada'` to make the image reload and fire the events.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser-independent way to detect when image has been loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded)

Comment: @adeneo maybe I was unclear. `img.src = img.src` does work, I'm just looking for something better.

Comment: @CMedina not a duplicate, that question regards images that haven't yet loaded.

Comment: "I'd be much more comfortable with a solution that doesn't assume optimizations". So no relying on cache?

Comment: Oh, okay, I assumed `img.src = img.src` didn't work in all browsers, but that's probably just older IE, which doesn't fire the events when the image is already cached, and requires the `img.complete .. img.onload()` hack.

Comment: @JosephMarikle yes, it's rather ridiculous overhead when the task is just reading a boolean that's stored internally but apparently inaccessible. Also, Chrome doesn't even hit the cache here, just fires events, which would be fine but I don't think it's specified or reliable behavior.

Comment: @twhb I had an answer that I deleted, but it stated "Just treat it like a preloader. If the image has already been loaded, the browser will just load from cache, so very little overhead."  I had this code: https://jsfiddle.net/jtgb0fvv/.  Every modern browser should fire the events for the newly created image object.  Is that something that fits your needs?

Comment: @JosephMarikle thanks, but no, as I stated under `img.src = img.src` I'm requesting something without high overhead or relying on unspecified behavior.