# Add Event Listener for a DIV whenever it appear on page?

Tags: javascript

It like addEventListener("click"), but instead of click event, I want to change addEventListener("Is there abc DIV on page?")

```
document.addEventListener("Is there abc DIV on page?"){
   If yes{
       console.log("yes, there is abc div on page");
   }
   else{
       console.log("no, there is no abc div on page");
   }
}

//User can toggle the presence of abc div whenever they want
document.addEventListener("click/keyboard/...."){
     Remove abc div or Add abc div;
}
```

Every time User toggle the presence of abc div, this Event Listener will catch and notice the change.

Thank you

Comment: Is [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) what you're looking for? Generally it allows you to run callbacks whenever the DOM changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining if a HTML element has been added to the DOM dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618876/determining-if-a-html-element-has-been-added-to-the-dom-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
      function add_abc_div(){
        var abc = document.getElementById('abc');
        if(abc){
         alert('ABC div already exist!');
         return false;
        }
        var test = document.getElementById('test');
        test.innerHTML = test.innerHTML + '<div id="abc">this is ABC div</div>';
      }
      function remove_abc_div(){
        var abc = document.getElementById('abc');
        if(abc){
          abc.remove();
        }
      }
      function my_event(){
        var abc = document.getElementById('abc');
        if(!abc){
         alert('not found ABC');
        }else{
           alert('found ABC');
        }
      }
      document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', my_event, false);
```

```css
        #test{
         border-style: solid;
         border-width: 1px;
         height: 100px;
         width: 100px;
         text-align: center;
         cursor: pointer;
        }
        #abc{
         background-color : gray;
        }
```

```html
<div id="test">Click Me!</div>
<input type="button" value="add ABC div" onclick="add_abc_div()" /></br>
<input type="button" value="remove ABC div" onclick="remove_abc_div()" />
```

Comment: Thank but this solution is not for my problem,  Event Listener should auto checking ABC Div, not clicking to check!

Answer (score 0):

By "div on page", do you mean "displayed", "created in DOM" or both ?

**Div on page > displayed**

I would simply get the div.style.displayed value.

**Div on page > created in DOM**

When creating the div, I would give it a specific class or data- value.

```
<div class="specific-div" style="display:none"></div>

const isDisplayed = document.getElementsByClassName('specific-div')[0].style.display !== 'none';
// or
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('specific-div');
divs.forEach(div => doSomething());
```