# GWT Node or Element listen to onAttach event

Tags: java, gwt

Is there a way to handle sort of onAttach event in GWT Node? I suppose I could do like this:

```
Node myDiv = DOM.createDiv();
Magic.setOnAttachEventListener(myDiv, new EventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onEvent(Event event) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The handler should be invoked when I do something like this,

```
parent.appendChild(myDiv);
```

given that the `parent` is attached itself, i.e., it is displayed in the current window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post my second answer as now I know that you can't change the way how DIVs are added to the parent.

After some searching I found [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). They allow you to listen to `DOMNodeInserted` event:

JS:

```
myDiv.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
    alert('added');
}, false);
```

In GWT you need to use JSNI method:

```
private native void addListener(Element elem) /*-{
    elem.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
        $wnd.alert('added');
    }, false);
}-*/;
```

It works, but... it's deprecated. You should use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.

Unfortunately `MutationObserver` don't have NodeInserted event to be observed. I thought that `subtree` mutation observation would do the job but it didn't work for me. The solution is to observe `childList` mutation on the parent:

JS:

```
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        alert(mutation.type);
    });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = {
    childList: true
};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(elem, config);
```

And, again, for GWT you need to wrap it in JSNI method (you know how).

The `mutation` parameter in observer callback is a [MutationRecord](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) object.

So, if you can get the parent, use MutationObserver on it and observe `childList` mutation. If not, try to use the deprecated Mutation events.

---

I know that this is not pure GWT solution, but you can use GWT methods to handle event or mutation. You just need to call GWT method form JSNI like this:

```
[instance-expr.]@class-name::method-name(param-signature)(arguments)
```

You'll find all JSNI info in the [GWT documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

Answer (score 1):

All `Widget`s in GWT already implement [HasAttachHandlers](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/HasAttachHandlers.html) interface. If you need this functionality, you may be better off using a Widget instead of a Node.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm clutched with some framework limitations and can't switch to Widgets.

Comment: Then look at how Widgets implement this interface. It's not that trivial if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimplePanel` or `HTMLPanel` as both use `DIV` for its contents.

On Panels you can call `addAttachHandler` method.

If you need an `Element` you can call `getElement()` method on the Panel.

This method works only if you attach `myDiv` as a Panel, so instead of

```
parent.appendChild(myDiv);
```

you should do this

```
HTMLPanel.wrap(parent).add(myDiv);
```

Here is an example code:

```
    Element parent = RootPanel.getBodyElement();
    SimplePanel myDiv = new SimplePanel();

    // use it as Panel
    myDiv.add(new Label("Hello!"));

    // or use it as an element
    myDiv.getElement().setInnerText("Hello 2!");

    myDiv.addAttachHandler(new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            Window.alert("Attached");
        }
    });

//  parent.appendChild(myDiv.getElement());     // this will not fire the AttachEvent
    HTMLPanel.wrap(parent).add(myDiv);          // this will fire the AttachEvent
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the way parent adds `myDiv`. If I could I would handle that "by hands" right after adding an element to a parent in whatever way.

Answer (score 0):

There is also "polling" alternative which may be not very effective but easier, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/850995/938899.